# Где и как хранить адрес текущего кошелька пользователя МетаМуска для бэкэнда?

Tags: веб-программирование, веб-сервер, сессия, блокчейн

Есть вэб приложение, которое **отображает** кое-какую информацию о NFT текущего пользователя на различных страницах. Данные о NFT запрашиваются не через браузер, а на бэкэнде, через сторонний API. Запросы происходят при загрузке страницы - не через AJAX. То есть, страница полностью генерится **на сервере**.

Сейчас используется тестовый, статический кошелёк, зашитый в коде. Мне, разумеется, нужно, чтобы это был кошелёк **текущего, аутентифицированного через МетаМуск пользователя.**

**Вопрос:** как бы этот кошелёк, после аутентификации, лучше всего а) передавать на сервер и б) где или как его сохранять?

Пользователь может менять аккаунты в МетаМуске, когда ему заблагорассудится, конечно, и нужно это учесть. Может разлогиниваться. И текущий кошель, или отсутствие оного, должно синхронизироваться с сервером - чтобы я там мог доставать NFT для этого кошелька.

Варианты:

- Сохранять его в куке и читать её при каждом запросе, на сервере
- Передавать через ajax и сохранять, например, в сессию. Или в базу

Что лучше? Будут ли проблемы с кукой?